# Video keeps on playing even when modal box is closed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

I am embedding a Wistia video to open in a modal box.
I have embedded the same fine, but the video still keeps on playing when I close the modal box.

Code as below.

**The HTML**

```
<a target="_self" class="wistia_embed" name="wistia_embed" id="myImg">Watch Now</a>
<div id="myModal" class="modal">  
  <iframe allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" class="wistia_embed modal-content" name="wistia_embed" src="https://fast.wistia.com/embed/iframe/g5pnf59ala" width="480" height="273"></iframe>
  <div id="caption"></div>
</div>
```

**The Script:**

```
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
var img = document.getElementById('myImg');
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
img.onclick = function(){
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = this.src;
    captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}
var modal = document.getElementsByClassName("modal")[0];
modal.onclick = function() { 
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

**JSFiddle demo link:**

**[FIDDLE LIVE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/6aku0dzp/)**

When you click on Watch now, the video opens. When you click outside, the modal closes, but the video still plays.

I want the video to close when the modal is closed, but its not working for me.
Secondly, I would also want the video to autoplay when you click on "watch Now".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (updated):

https://jsfiddle.net/tonnjngm/

```
var modal = document.getElementsByClassName("modal")[0];
modal.onclick = function() { 
    modal.style.display = "none";
    var src = modal.querySelector('iframe').getAttribute('src');
    modal.querySelector('iframe').setAttribute('src', src);
}
```

Resetting `src` kind of stops the video.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. +1. It does stop on the fiddle. Let me check on my back-end to see if it works or not. Also, it is still not autoplaying when its clicked.

Comment: Works fine .. Thank you .. Accepted the answer.